# cURL PHP Extension suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, curl, fedora

In my PHP file I have a line which checks that the curl extension is loaded:

`if (!extension_loaded('curl')) { trigger_error("Curl Extension not loaded", E_USER_ERROR); die(); }`

On Friday, everything was working normally. Today when I attempted to run the file, I get my error message:

> Fatal error: Curl Extension not loaded in /usr/share/pear/jsinfo.class.php on line 23 
>   Blockquote

I've tried reinstalling both cURL and the PHP cURL extension. I've restarted the httpd service and also rebooted the server. Nothing has fixed this problem. This is on Fedora 15.

Any ideas as to what could have happened/how I can fix this?

Comment: What's in `phpinfo()`?  What does your PHP.ini look like?

Comment: Someone made a php update on the server and forgot to compile the extension? Did you enable the php extension in php.ini if it is not compiled with php? Maybe using php on the command line where a different php.ini is used?

Comment: The only thing mentioned about curl in phpinfo() is a command: '--without-curl'. Is that causing the problem? How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the extension directive for curl in the php.ini.

There should be something like

```
extension=curl.so
```

Comment: I added this and curl is showing up in phpinfo() now. I still don't understand why it would change like that though.